# Poisson process and ship insurance with binomial damage claim

Tags: probability, statistics, poisson-process

A insurance company offers ship owners insurance for broken down ships. For the calculation assume that the reported broken down ships follow a poission process. On average a breakdown happens on $1$ day out of $1000$ days and the damage is $\text{Binomial($2\cdot 10^7,0.5$)}$ distributed and is independent of the damage of other ships and independent of the poisson process. Calculate the expected damage in one year ($365$ days).

I am having trouble "merging" the poisson process with the binomial damage claim. I basically have two random variables $$X:=\text{number of broken down ships} \sim Poi(\frac{1}{1000}) \\ Y:= \text{damage of broken down ship} \sim Bin(2\cdot 10^7,0.5)$$

How can I put these together to find the expected damage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there are a random number $X$ of damaged ships, and each one has damage $Y_i$, then the total damage is

$$\mathbf E \left[ \sum_{i=1}^X Y_i \right].$$

[Wald's equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wald%27s_equation) allows you to calculate the expectation of a random sum of random variables, under the condition that the terms of the sum are independent and identically distributed.

$$\mathbf E \left[ \sum_{i=1}^X Y_i \right] = \mathbf E[X] \mathbf E[Y].$$

In your case this becomes

$$\mathbf E \left[ \sum_{i=1}^X Y_i \right] = \left(\frac{365}{1000}\right) \times \left( \frac12 \times 2 \cdot 10^7\right) = 3.65 \times 10^6$$

Comment: This is the first time I have seen Wald's equation and it seems very useful. Thank you very much for your help!